# Убрать повторяющиеся значения массива в строке

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с вопросом

Есть массив

```
$staff_all = array(
    '1' => " инженер авто или жд дорог",
    '2' => " инженер автомобильных дорог",
    '3' => " инженер-ВК",
    '4' => " инженер-газонефтепровода",
    '5' => " инженер-КиП",
    '6' => " инженер-мостов и тоннелей",
    '7' => " инженер-нефтяник"
);
```

И есть еще один массив

```
$subspecies_all = array(
'1' => "Планировочной документации (комплексных схем градостроительного планирования территорий - проектов районной планировки, генеральных планов населенных пунктов, проектов детальной планировки и проектов застройки районов, микрорайонов, кварталов, отдельных участков)\n",
'2' => "Схем развития транспортной инфраструктуры населенных пунктов (улично-дорожной сети и объектов внутригородского и внешнего транспорта, располагаемых в пределах границ населенных пунктов) и межселенных территорий (объектов и коммуникаций внешнего транспорта, располагаемых вне улично-дорожной сети населенных пунктов)\n",
'3' => "Схем теплоснабжения населенных пунктов с размещением объектов по производству и транспортировке тепловой энергии в системе застройки, а также теплоснабжения производственных комплексов, располагаемых на межселенных территориях\n",
'4' =>"Схем водоснабжения населенных пунктов с размещением источников питьевой и (или) технической воды и трассированием водоводов, а также схем водоснабжения производственных комплексов, располагаемых на межселенных территориях\n",
'5' => "Схем канализации населенных пунктов и производственных комплексов, включая централизованную систему сбора и отвода бытовых, производственных и ливневых стоков, размещение головных очистных сооружений, испарителей и объектов по регенерации стоков\n",
'6' => "Схем газоснабжения населенных пунктов и производственных комплексов, располагаемых на межселенных территориях\n"
);
```

На странице есть несколько checkbox-ов, при выборе которых формируется строка с выбранными значениями $subspecies_all.

И формируется ещё одна строка в зависимости от пунктов которые были выбраны в $subspecies_all.

Например были выбраны "Планировочная документация" и "Схем развития транспортной инфраструктуры". Сформировалась вторая строка с необходимыми специалистами "Нам необходимы: инженер автомобильных дорог, инженер-КиП."

Но если выбрать "Планировочная документация" и "Схем развития транспортной инфраструктуры" и "Схем водоснабжения населенных пунктов". То сформированная вторая строка будет такой "Нам необходимы: инженер автомобильных дорог, инженер-КиП, инженер автомобильных дорог." То есть будет повтор необходимого специалиста "инженер автомобильных дорог"

У меня это выглядит так

```
if ($subspecies_all['1'] == 1) {
    $podkategorii = $podkategorii . $subspecies_all['1']; #Первая строка
    $specialisti = $specialisti . $necessary_staff_all['1']; #Строка со специалистами
}
if ($subspecies_all['2'] == 1) {
    $podkategorii = $podkategorii . $subspecies_all['2']; #Первая строка
    $specialisti = $specialisti . $necessary_staff_all['2']; #Строка со специалистами
}
if ($subspecies_all['3'] == 1) {
    $podkategorii = $podkategorii . $subspecies_all['3']; #Первая строка
    $specialisti = $specialisti . $necessary_staff_all['1']; #Строка со специалистами
}
echo $podkategorii;
echo $specialisti;
```

Помогите отсортировать строку так, чтобы специалист повторялся только один раз.

Спасибо!

Comment: [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: вообще без кода того как все это у вас происходит, корректный ответ вам никто не даст.

Comment: Я добавил пример того как это работает у меня

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вам нужно формировать не строку а обрезанный массив, а потом уже из него сделать строку

У вас есть массив $subspecies_all, у него уникальные ключи

Сделайте промежуточный массив

```
$table = [1=>2,2=>5,4=>2];//здесь ключи это ключи как у $subspecies_all, a значения - ключи $staff_all
```

Дальше собираем выбранные значения в строку

```
$result = [];
foreach($subspecies_all as $key=>$value){
  if( $value == 1) $result[ $key ] = $staff_all[ $table[$key] ];//здесь мы получаем что то вроде [1=>" инженер автомобильных дорог",2=>" инженер-КиП",4=>" инженер автомобильных дорог"]
}
$podkategorii = '';
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
  $podkategorii .= $subspecies_all[$key];
}
$specialisti = array_unique( $result );
$specialisti = implode ( $specialisti );
echo $podkategorii;
echo $specialisti;
```